# Combining joined tag search with other parameters in RT sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, real-time, sphinx

We use sphinx with a RealTime (RT) index to search through our database. Right now it contains fields such as longitude, latitude, title, content and it´s all working fine. The problem is that we want to implement a relational Tag-table and we are not sure how to do it.

In our current configuration we take advantage of a lot of the preconfigured methods available in the sphinxApi (for php), such as:

```
 $this->_sphinxClient->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);

$this->_sphinxClient->SetGeoAnchor('latitude', 'longitude', (float)$this->latitude, (float)$this->longitude);

$this->_sphinxClient->SetFilterRange('price', $this->_priceMin, $this->_priceMax);

// And getting the final result with the:
$result = $this->_sphinxClient->Query($this->searchString, 'rt');
```

What we like to do if possible is either use mva (multi value attribute) or search through the results a second time with a join statement and seeding out the results that contain none of the tags.

We can´t get any of these options to work at the moment, so if anyone has any idea I would love a little help here. Use another index with id/tagname combination or a string attribute in the current one? Implement the search in the same query as the first one or search through those results in a second query with the tagjoin?

If I have missed anything important here please let me know, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Attach the tags to the current index. If you just need to search them, insert the tags in a full-text field and a string attribute if you want to get the tags as well in result. If you need to do grouping, you can:

- use a MVA, but you will need to make a map between tag name and a tag id
- use a JSON attribute. You can use IN on an array of strings like for MVA. For something more advanced you can use ALL() or ANY() functions.

For grouping, remember to use SetArrayResult(true). Also I recommend switching to SphinxQL interface.